# Altering an ASP Web Forms Button's Enable property with Code?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I'm learning ASP Web Forms for a project (yes it needs to be Web Forms) and am seeking some help for an issue with the following code:

```
<a href="Calendar.aspx?trackId=<%#:Item.TrackId %>">
    <asp:Button ID="addResultsBtn" runat="server" Text="Add Results" Enabled="<%#:(bool)(Item.RaceDate <= DateTime.Now)%>" />
</a>
<br />
```

I'm trying to either Enable or Disable a button depending on whether or not the date is in the past.

As far as I can tell, the code to determine the 'Enabled' property of the asp:Button is returning a bool, and yet I'm getting the following error:

```
CS0030: Cannot convert type 'string' to 'bool'
```

I'm assuming the double quotes must remain in the Enabled(="") property declaration, but I've even tried removing these and converting it to string and simply removing them and leaving it as a bool. I'm sure I could get this to work with some JavaScript, but it seems like this should be such a simple solution and I can't understand why it doesn't recognise the bool?

Cheers guys!

Answer (score 0):

<%#: {code} %> <-- This converts the code to a string format, what I needed was:

<%# {code} %> <-- WITHOUT the colon (:)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft docs has many good examples explaining each asp.net web form inline expression syntax.

You can check out on the link below, very good info.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/aspnet/inline-expressions